# Display Sub Categories list on a Category Page in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, category, category-listing

1. How To Display Sub Categories list on a Category Page in Magento 2.3

   ```
   root_catalog
    |-First  |-Shoes
            |-T-shirts
    |-Brands
    |-Demo
    |-Test
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below blog for answer

https://meetanshi.com/blog/display-magento-2-subcategories-with-image-on-category-page/